How do I use find_elements() in Selenium Python?
I'm working through a Mercury Tours demo using Python on https://demo.guru99.com/selenium/newtours/reservation.php.
I'm trying to use find_elements().
In the first piece of code, I'm trying to click the 'Type' radio button 'One Way' i.e. Index[1]:
radiotripType = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'tripType') 
radiotripType.select_by_index[1].click() 

In the 2nd piece of code I'm trying to click the 'Service Class' radio button 'First Class':
radioCategory = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'serveClass').click("First")

I know I can use find_elements() with By.XPath, which I can do, but I'm looking to gain experience with find_elements(). Any help would be appreciated.

find_elements() returns a list of all elements that matched the search.  What is your actual question?

Is the code you posted not working? If it's working, then you apparently know how to use it.

radiotripType.select_by_index[1].click() This code can't work, because radiotripType is a list, and lists don't have a .select_by_index attribute.

In the first piece of code I get a list and am trying to click the radio button for the 2nd item on the list, the demo mentioned using Index[1] but that's in Java I believe so I'm looking to do same in Python.

In the 2nd piece of code I'm trying to click on the 3rd item on the list returned.

Since radiotripType is a list, you can just use radiotripType[1].click()

@JohnGordon Thank you so much for the answer, that's exactly what I needed. I'm new to coding and spent ages going through it, your solution makes it look so easy. The training I'm following is in Java so unfortunately I ended up down a hole with looking at select_by_index etc

Can I ask how I go about using or getting at the information within the list e.g. the values for each of the Input type, name and value for Index 0 and 1? (....I hope this makes sense...). For example if I wanted to have an assertion to ensure [0] value=roundtrip and [1] value=oneway.
This relates to the 2nd part of my code radioCategory = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'serveClass')    I tried to put  .click("First") so that it clicks the 'value=first' for 'First Class' radio button but I think I'm missing something as it says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'.

This code returns a list of elements if any found, you'll need to use [index] to execute click on it. Otherwise you'll get attribute error
radioCategory = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'serveClass')
if radioCategory:
    radioCategory[0].click("First")

Note: Click does not take parameters, so having "First" will cause an error
As for locator that'll be something like this
driver.find_element(By.XPAATH, "//input[@name='servClass']")

XPATH is pretty good for finding elements.
Here is decent tutorial: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/xpath-locators-cheat-sheet
